# Overriding RequestMapping on SpringMVC controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Looking through the source for our applications, I found a common Spring MVC controller which display key and values of configuration copied and pasted several times.  The class definitions are exactly the same, except for the RequestMapping value, since each application want to have this page available under different URLs.

I want to move this controller into a common library, and provide a default RequestMapping value.

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping (value="/property")
public class CommonPropertyController {
   ....
}
```

How would each application override this value if they want to use their own url pattern?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the source code I got an idea how to do it without having to go back to manual (pre-annotation) handler definition (which is also a way how to implement what you need).

Spring allows you to use property placeholder configurers in `@RequestMapping` values. So it is possible to use that fact and define `@RequestMapping` like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${routing.property.path}")
public class CommonPropertyController {
    ....
}
```

Then you can simply define `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` with the right properties in your application context and you are good to go.

---

**UPDATE** You can also specify a default value using property placeholder if you want to have fallback mapping in case the property is not speciefied:

```
@RequestMapping("${routing.property.path:/property}")
```

Comment: This has the extra benefit of disabling the controller if property is not present.  Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to disable the controller this way. It will be mapped to the placeholder itself or you might get error about unresolved property... Btw. I've also noticed that the placeholder behaviour is mentioned in `@RequestMapping` JavaDoc :)

Comment: Browsing through documentation there is even better feature - you can specify default value in property placeholders: `@RequestMapping("${routing.property.path:/property}")`. Will add this to the answer.