# @RequestMapping with placeholder not working

Tags: spring-mvc

So i have spend hours to try to get the anwser of this post working:
[Overriding RequestMapping on SpringMVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17128463/overriding-requestmapping-on-springmvc-controller)

But it really is not working. What I have so far:

springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:numbernick.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.numbernick" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

And I've got a Controller:

```
@Value("${requestmapping.test}")
private String test;

@RequestMapping("${requestmapping.test}.html")
public ModelAndView test() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName(test.html);

    log.debug("Test: "+test);
    return mav;
}
```

numbernick.properties:

```
requestmapping.test=myUrl
```

This should work fine. When I call the page, I get a logmessage saying "Test: myUrl"
. BUT! this comes when I call "/${requestmapping.test},html". And it should work with calling "/myUrl.html". I have absolutely no Idea why it is this way. Obviously the PropertyPlaceholder works and doesn't work at the same time. (BTW: It is a nested RequestMapping. But it also doesn't work at topLvl-RequestMapping as well)

How can this be and what can I do to fix this? I'm currently working with spring verion 3.2.8

Comment: Is EL in an `@RequestMapping` a thing?  I have never seen this before, so if it is, this is new to me.

Comment: Well that's how it is in the documentation as well: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong, I was just surprised this worked.  I knew you could put placeholders using `{...}` for `@PathVariable`s, and even knew those could use regex.  I guess I just never read the part that said you could use EL to plop in property values in your `@RequestMapping`.  It never ceases to amaze me the level of detail the Spring folks put into their api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem also and solved it once I realized that a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean wasn't loaded into the context of the module where many of the placeholders existed.

Simple solution was to refactor our externalized configuration.  In the end, I moved the `@PropertySources` definition and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to a common module and all is well:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:app-config.properties")})
public class ExternalizedConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

The request mappings like this work as expected now:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/${foo.bar.rest_proxy_uri}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In fact, on server startup, you will see the placeholders have been resolved:

```
2015-05-06 16:21:52 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/restProxy/**],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> foo.bar.web.controllers.RestfulFooBarProxyController.proxyGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```