# Spring Boot REST Controller Test with RequestMapping of Properties Value

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-boot

Regarding Unit Testing of Spring Boot REST Controller, I got a problem with @RequestMapping and application properties.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( "${base.url}" )
public class RESTController {
    @RequestMapping( value = "/path/to/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
    public String getStuff( @PathVariable String param ) {
        // implementation of stuff
    }
}
```

I am working with several profiles for the application and therefore I have several `application-{profile}.properties` files. In each file the `base.url` property value is set and present. I also have a different Spring Context Configuration for testing, which only differs in just one Bean from the productive version.

My Unit Test looks like the following, with using JUNit and Mockito / RestAssured:

```
@ActiveProfiles( "dev" )
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = SpringContextConfigTest.class )
public class RESTControllerTest {

private static final String SINGLE_INDIVIDUAL_URL = "/query/api/1/individuals/";

@InjectMocks
private RESTController restController;

@Mock  
private Server mockedServer; // needed for the REST Controller to forward

@Before
public void setup() {
  RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc( MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(restController).build() );
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
}

@Test
public void testGetStuff() throws Exception {
  // test the REST Method "getStuff()"
}
```

Problem is, that the REST Controller is working when started in the production mode. In the unit test mode, the `${base.url}` value is not set and an exception is thrown, when building the mockMvc object:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base.url' in string value "${base.url}"`

I also tried it with the following approaches, but with different exceptions:

- `@IntegrationTest` on Test,
- `@WebAppConfiguration`,
- using the `webApplicationContext` to build the MockMVC
- autowiring the RESTController in the Test
- defining the REST Controller Bean in the SpringContextConfigTest Class manually

and various other combinations, but nothing seems to work.
So how do I have to go on, in order to make it work?
I think it's a Context configuration issue with the two different config classes, but I don't know how to solve it or how to do it "right".

Comment: Could you provide a minimal but complete standalone project which illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with using one `application.yml` file instead of profile-properties.
The yml file is using a standard definition for the `default` profile, which is defined at the top of the file.

```
#default settings. these can be overriden for each profile.
#all these settings are overriden by env vars by spring priority
rest:
  api:
    version: 1
base:
   url: /query/api/${rest.api.version}
---
spring:
   profiles: dev
---
spring:
   profiles: production
main:
  show_banner: true
---
spring:
   profiles: test
base:
   url: /query/override/default/value
```

Answer (score 4):

You will be required to add placeholder value to teh stand alone setup -

```
mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(youController).addPlaceholderValue(name, value);
```

Comment: If the only purpose of @ActiveProfiles("dev") is to import the placeholder, then that annotation can be removed with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in non-production mode property placeholders can't be resolved. You definitely want to look into [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) documentation page.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087115/4618338) could also provide some help with implementation.