# RequestMapping placeholders don't work in JUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have a simple Spring MVC controller whose RequestMapping is a property. It's a jar that include a controller. Downstream apps will take this jar and use the common endpoint, only the precise URL can vary by app)

Everything works fine when I include my jar into another app. The app has a property or yaml file and the property is set. I've verified that the endpoint works fine.

However, being the good developer that I am, I want to make an integration test that verifies that the URL determined by the property is exposed properly. I can get an @Value in the controller injected properly, but a ${} expression in the @RequestMapping will not be substituted from a properties file. I found a couple threads ([Spring Boot REST Controller Test with RequestMapping of Properties Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410962/spring-boot-rest-controller-test-with-requestmapping-of-properties-value) and [@RequestMapping with placeholder not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395984/requestmapping-with-placeholder-not-working/30087115#30087115)) But either they don't apply or I tried what they said and I couldn't get it to work.

The test that hits the static (iWork) endpoint works, but the one that is pulled from the property (iDontWork) doesn't work.

(This is Spring 4.2.6)

## Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/${appName}", "/iWork"})
public class Controller {

    @Value("${appName}")
    private String appName;

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handlerMethod (HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        // Proves the placeholder is injected in the class, but
        // Not in the RequestMapping
        assert appName != null;
        assert !appName.equals("${appName}");
        return "";
    }
}
```

## ControllerTest

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class,
    classes = { ControllerTest.Config.class })
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .build();
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"test"})
    static class Config {
        // because @PropertySource doesnt work in annotation only land
        @Bean
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig() {
            PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
            ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("test.properties"));
            return ppc;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testStaticEndpoint() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/iWork")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testDynamicEndpoint() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/iDontWork")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

## test.properties

```
appName = iDontWork
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're "simply" missing

```
@EnableWebMvc
```

on your `@Configuration` class. Without it, Spring's Mock MVC stack will register your controller handler methods with `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` which isn't smart enough to resolve the placeholders in `@RequestMapping`.

If you **do** provide it, Mock MVC will instead use `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, which is.

Answer (score 1):

> You need to add placeholder value while creating mockMvc as shown below.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(accountController)
                .addPlaceholderValue("propertyName", "propertyValue")
                .build();
}
```