# Injecting properties into annotation values

Tags: java, spring

I would like to feed some annotation values with properties 
from my application context property-placeholder.

The problem is that I am not finding a way to inject the properties in either into the annotation value or into a non-managed static Constants class.

How would you solve that?

i.e:

```
@POST
@Path("/my-endpoint")
@Consumes("${myendpoint.versionAsMediaType}")
```

Comment: I think what you trying to do here is using Jersey. You should look at [this spring-mvc example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30087115/2745277) . Spring has better support for spring-mvc than jersey

Comment: Value "injection" in annotations will only work for annotations that are parsed by Spring not for other annotations. And even then it has to be done manually, check for instance the `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which checks if a value is set and tries to resolve it. So it will only work for annotations that have meaning in Spring and are processed by yourself.